# python boto3 multipart upload to buckets in different zones

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I followed s3 documentation and example for uploading my large file as multipart to amazon s3 storages with using a boto3 library. However, the information in official documentation was not sufficient for me.  In my case, I have multiple storages in different regions, and I should upload my parts (overall, 500 GB) to different storages. I would like to see an example, how to upload multiple parts to different S3 storages in different zones with using the boto3 library. Any information is valuable for me. Thank you for reading

[boto3 documentaion](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.create_multipart_upload)

[boto3 example](https://bcbio.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/parallel-upload-to-amazon-s3-with-python-boto-and-multiprocessing/)

Comment: What do you mean by "upload multiple parts to different S3 storages"? An object must be uploaded to a single region. You are welcome to upload to multiple regions, but they would be uploaded as separate objects. Could you possibly edit your question to explain _WHY_ you wish to do this? We can then probably come up with a recommended method.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, hi John. Thanks for the response. I have math model, which I want to test implementation multipart upload (As in this link at tip 6 was said [link](https://www.sumologic.com/aws/s3/10-things-might-not-know-using-s3/) ). My problem is I want to separate single large object and upload that to different storages, instead of one storage one object principles. If the info in the link is correct that means I should be able to do that.But I have no idea how

Comment: I also read official [doc](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/boto3/latest/boto3.pdf). But couldn't find info that  can do this or not

Comment: What do you mean by "different storages"? That is not a normal term. Please explain your goal in more detail.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein. let's say you have two different buckets in two different zones. Like one of them in OHIO and the second one in London. I have an object which is 50GB (example). Now I want to set that (I don't know how still), 20 GB of this object uploaded to S3 storage in London, 30 GB in OHIO.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein. I know multipart principles is upload the single object to the single storage. But I would like to know in case I will have single object with size of the 10TB, what I will do? because as far I know, I can only upload maximum 5TB data to single storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you seem to be confused about some of the terminology. Let's define some terms:

- **Region:** A geographic location containing multiple Availability Zones, eg London, Ohio
- **Availability Zone:** A data centre (or multiple). Each AZ in a region is geographically separated to ensure *High Availability*.
- **Regional service:** A few services, including **Amazon S3** is a *regional service*. This means it automatically copies data amongst the AZs.
- **Bucket:** Storage location for objects in Amazon S3. A bucket exists in *only one region*.
- **Object:** A *file* in a bucket.

Now, to answer your questions:

**An object exists in one bucket only.** An object cannot be split between buckets. (And since a bucket exists i na region, it cannot also be split between regions.)

If you wish to replicate objects between regions, use *Cross-Region Replication*. This will automatically copies objects from one bucket to another.

The maximum size of an object in Amazon S3 is 5TB, but you *really, really* don't want to get that large. Most big data applications use *many, smaller files* (eg 5MB in size). This allows *parallel loading* across multiple processes, which is commonly done in Hadoop. It also allows the additional of new data by simply adding files, rather than updating an existing file. (By the way, you cannot *append* to an S3 object, you can only replace it.)

The easiest way to upload data to S3 is by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Multi-part uploads are merely a means of uploading a single object by splitting it into multiple parts, uploading each part, then stitching them together. The method of upload is unrelated to the actual objects once they have been uploaded.

You should always store your data close to where it is being processed. So, only replicate data between regions if it needs to be processed in multiple regions.